# Using Widget To Display Multiple Graphs Within Main Window

Tags: python, pyside

I have 2 widgets inside of MainWindow, one of which is the main chart that will cover the top 1/3 of the page (StockChart) but the other widget needs to be made up of 4 graphs equally split up on the bottom 2/3 of the page (ExtraCharts), the problem is I'm having a hard time getting them to show up and even run without errors, here is the current code:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtCharts import *

from sqlite import MySql

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, db, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.setWindowTitle("Indicator Tool")

        self.db = db
        self.data = db.view_chart_data("5m")
        self.stockWidget = StockChart(self) 
        self.extraCharts = ExtraCharts(self)
        
        self.initUI()
        

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(1, 2)

        #Widget, row, column, rowspan, colspan
        grid.addWidget(self.stockWidget.chartView, 0, 0, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.extraCharts, 1, 0, 2, 2)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


class StockChart(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StockChart, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = parent.data
        self.drawChart()

    def drawChart(self):
        series = QCandlestickSeries()
        for row in self.data:
            time = row[1] * 1000
            open = row[2]
            high = row[3]
            low = row[4]
            close = row[5]
            volume = row[6]
            series.append(QCandlestickSet(open, high, low, close, time))

        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.legend().hide()
        self.chart.addSeries(series)
        self.chart.createDefaultAxes()
        self.chart.setTitle('/ES Candlestick Chart')

        self.chartView = QChartView(self.chart)
        self.chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)


class ExtraCharts(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ExtraCharts, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = parent.data
        self.drawChart()
        

    def drawChart(self):
        series = QCandlestickSeries()
        for row in self.data:
            time = row[1] * 1000
            open = row[2]
            high = row[3]
            low = row[4]
            close = row[5]
            volume = row[6]
            series.append(QCandlestickSet(open, high, low, close, time))

        chart_1 = QChart()
        chart_1.legend().hide()
        chart_1.addSeries(series)
        chart_1.createDefaultAxes()
        chart_1.setTitle('Chart 1')

        chart_2 = QChart()
        chart_2.legend().hide()
        chart_2.addSeries(series)
        chart_2.createDefaultAxes()
        chart_2.setTitle('Chart 2')

        chart_3 = QChart()
        chart_3.legend().hide()
        chart_3.addSeries(series)
        chart_3.createDefaultAxes()
        chart_3.setTitle('Chart 3')

        chart_4 = QChart()
        chart_4.legend().hide()
        chart_4.addSeries(series)
        chart_4.createDefaultAxes()
        chart_4.setTitle('Chart 4')

        chartView_1 = QChartView(chart_1)
        chartView_1.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        chartView_2 = QChartView(chart_2)
        chartView_2.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        chartView_3 = QChartView(chart_3)
        chartView_3.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        chartView_4 = QChartView(chart_4)
        chartView_4.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        # grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        # grid.setRowStretch(1, 2)
        #Widget, row, column, rowspa, colspan
        grid.addWidget(chartView_1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(chartView_2, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(chartView_3, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(chartView_4, 1, 1)
        
        chart_1.show()
        chart_2.show()
        chart_3.show()
        chart_4.show()
        



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    db = MySql()
    window = MainWindow(db)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

and as of right now im getting this error:

```
"Can not find axis on the chart."
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know my method of doing this is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a QXSerie can only be part of a QChart, and in your case you are creating violating that rule.

On the other hand, it is not good to access parent properties such as data, instead it is better to make the method receive the data.

```py
import sys
from functools import cached_property

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGridLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide6.QtCharts import QCandlestickSeries, QCandlestickSet, QChart, QChartView

from sqlite import MySql


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, db, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.setWindowTitle("Indicator Tool")

        self.db = db
        data = db.view_chart_data("5m")

        self.stockWidget = StockChart()
        self.extraCharts = ExtraCharts()

        self.stockWidget.drawChart(data)
        self.extraCharts.drawChart(data)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        grid.setRowStretch(1, 2)

        grid.addWidget(self.stockWidget, 0, 0, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.extraCharts, 1, 0, 2, 2)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)


class StockChart(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.chart_view)

    @cached_property
    def chart_view(self):
        chart = QChart()
        chart.legend().hide()
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart.setTitle("/ES Candlestick Chart")
        view = QChartView(chart)
        view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        return view

    def drawChart(self, data):
        series = QCandlestickSeries()
        for row in data:
            time = row[1] * 1000
            open = row[2]
            high = row[3]
            low = row[4]
            close = row[5]
            volume = row[6]
            series.append(QCandlestickSet(open, high, low, close, time))
        self.chart_view.chart().addSeries(series)


class ExtraCharts(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    @cached_property
    def views(self):
        return list()

    def init_ui(self):
        grid = QGridLayout(self)

        positions = (
            (0, 0, "Chart 1"),
            (0, 1, "Chart 2"),
            (1, 0, "Chart 3"),
            (1, 1, "Chart 4"),
        )
        for (row, column, title) in positions:
            view = QChartView()
            view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            view.chart().setTitle(title)
            view.chart().legend().hide()
            view.chart().createDefaultAxes()

            grid.addWidget(view, row, column)
            self.views.append(view)

    def drawChart(self, data):
        for view in self.views:
            series = QCandlestickSeries()
            view.chart().addSeries(series)
            for row in data:
                time = row[1] * 1000
                open = row[2]
                high = row[3]
                low = row[4]
                close = row[5]
                volume = row[6]
                series.append(QCandlestickSet(open, high, low, close, time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    db = MySql()
    window = MainWindow(db)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: This does work though the data is not being inputted into the graph, but i think you lead me into the right enough direction.

Comment: Do actually any of the charts work for you? For me its just showing the blank Widget i believe?